# Customize time picker

Tags: android, kotlin, timepicker

Is it possible to customize the standart time picker as in the below picture?

[The time picker i want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNRT5.png)

I can create my own time picker with the below code:

```
    mTimePicker = TimePickerDialog(this, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK , {
            _, hourOfDay, min -> selectedTime.text = String.format("%d : %d", hourOfDay, min) },
        hour, minute, true)

    selectedTime.setOnClickListener {
        mTimePicker.show()
    }
```

And result:

[My own Timepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4saqv.png)

I need to customize time picker somehow as in the first picture.

How can i do that?

Comment: The closest that you will get using framework widgets would be if you created your own time picker [using `NumberPicker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/NumberPicker).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom [DialogFragment](https://medium.com/@huseyinozkoc/how-to-use-dialogfragment-in-android-f8095dd0993f), add a [timePicker](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/timepicker-in-kotlin/) an the rest of the ui components such as buttons and the switch.